# Connecting to one database but querying another database with PHP and Firebird

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebird

I have a project in PHP Codeigniter and Firebird database. I'm connecting to my database, but I want to query other database (clients DB). If i do `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM arquiv");`, and in my DB config file I set the client DB, it runs OK and I get the results. The problem is that my DB configs are different. So I did:

```
$dbh = ibase_connect($this->session->userdata('client_db'),
    $this->session->userdata('client_username'), 
    $this->session->userdata('client_password'));
```

I checked all vars if they were correct and they were and the connection was successful, but when I do the following query, I get only the confirmation that the connection was successful, I don't get the results (and they exist) `$results = ibase_query($dbh, $query) or die(ibase_errmsg());`

Comment: Could you provide a [mre], and specify the PHP version and the exact version of the driver you're using. Also consider asking your question on the [firebird-php Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-php)

Comment: i suspect you did not sarted any transaction on the secondary connection. Can you just debug PHP program, line by line, inside the `$dbh = ibase_connect` call and see what it was doing there internally? Also assuming your firebird is 2.5 or newer you might try to spy on it using TraceAPI (FBProfiler.sf.net for an easy to use client) and thus see which requests come to it from your applicaito nand what server responds.